# Xamarin Forms: System.ObjectDisposedException when setting Focus to an Entry control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following Xamarin Forms page that throws an exception on this line...

[image]

The first time this page is loaded, the OnAppearing works fine, sets the focus properly, and doesn't throw an exception.

When I navigate back to this page (ie, logout), OnAppearing is throwing the following...

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.EntryRenderer'.

What is the best way to set focus to a control on a page in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: why are you calling FindByName?  InitializeComponent should generate references to all XAML objects for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is in your XAML, but if you define the `x:Name="_entry"` on the Entry in XAML, and use that name to access the control directly instead of `FindByName`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your issue at my side, but it works fine and there is no issue when I click Button to navigate another page and coming back. Please take a look my code:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="UserNameentry"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="btn1"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="200" />
    </StackLayout>

 public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var usernameentry = FindByName("UserNameentry") as Entry;
        usernameentry.Focus();
    }

    private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page3 page = new Page3();
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    }
```

If you still have this issue, please provide some code about xaml here.